# SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable() -- parent table first or child table?

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm creating a provisioning application using Microsoft sync framework 2.1 in a console application.  This application is used to provision the database only. Database has over 100 tables with many FK's.

Here is the question:
When I'm adding the tables to the scope, do I need to add the parent/top level table first before adding the child/tables which have FK's referencing the parent table?

When it's time to sync does the order in which I've added the table to the scope matter (meaning, can I add the child table first)?

Problem will come when it tries to inset a child record first before the parent record exists if the order of tables being added to the scope matters.

I hope this is clear enough to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the parent table first. The order of the tables in the provisioning is the same order used during synchronization.